# Execution of where clause in Haskell

Tags: haskell, where-clause

I got the following piece of code which I know that works but I am **completely new to Haskell** and got 2 questions about the where clause.

```
f3 :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f3 [] status = status --- Base Case
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status
 | status !! (p1-1) == 0  = f3 tail status  --- Case 1
 | status !! (p2-1) == 1  = f3 tail newStatus1 --- Case 2
 | otherwise = f3 tail newStatus2 --- Case 3
  where newStatus1 = set status p1 0                    --- Line 7
        newStatus2 = set newStatus2Temp p1 1            --- Line 8
        newStatus2Temp = set status p2 0                --- Line 9
```

So basically the f3 predicate has 2 arguments :

- A list of **Integer lists** like so : [[1,2],[2,3],[3,2]]
- An Integer list

It's output is the final updated second argument.

As you see besides the base case I got 2 cases (2) and (3) where the status/[Int] argument via **a standard set predicate**.

Question 1) :

- Say case 2 is true. Does Haskell execute lines 8 and 9 ?
- Say case 3 is true. Does Haskell execute line 7?

Question 2) :

- Can a guard have it's own where?
- Is there a better way to actually do this?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The actual homework was to ''translate" the f3 predicate from Prolog to Haskell. That's the way I came up with and I was wondering if the way I do it is not time efficient or something. By the way I have to carry the status argument and change it all the time but my question is mainly on the time impact of the where clause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a result of lazy evaluation, the code in each of lines 7-9 is only run if the value of the corresponding binding is evaluated/used in the course of evaluation of code for the case that matches.  So:

- If case 1 is true, none of lines 7-9 are run.
- If case 1 is false but case 2 is true, then evaluation of `newStatus` runs line 7, but lines 8-9 are not run.
- If cases 1 and 2 are false but case 3 is true, then evaluation of `newStatus2` runs line 8 which evaluates `newStatus2Temp` causing line 9 to run.  Line 7 is not run.

The `where` clauses themselves can only be attached to entire pattern bindings (e.g., the whole `f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status | ... | ...  = ...` expression), not individual guards, so a guard can't have its own `where` clause.  You could either repeat the pattern for each guard:

```
f3 :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f3 [] status = status
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status | status !! (p1-1) == 0  = f3 tail status
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status | status !! (p2-1) == 1  = f3 tail newStatus1
  where newStatus1 = set status p1 0
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status | otherwise              = f3 tail newStatus2
  where newStatus2 = set newStatus2Temp p1 1
        newStatus2Temp = set status p2 0
```

or use `let ... in ...` blocks:

```
f3 :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f3 [] status = status
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status
 | status !! (p1-1) == 0  = f3 tail status
 | status !! (p2-1) == 1
  = let newStatus1 = set status p1 0
    in f3 tail newStatus1
 | otherwise
  = let newStatus2 = set newStatus2Temp p1 1
        newStatus2Temp = set status p2 0
    in f3 tail newStatus2
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with your `where`-clause version, and it's not unusual to write Haskell code where only a subset of the bindings in the `where`-clause are used (or even valid/meaningful) for each case.  With such small helpers, this specific example might be more clearly written without any helpers though:

```
f3 :: [[Int]] -> [Int] -> [Int]
f3 [] status = status
f3 ([p1,p2]:tail) status
 | status !! (p1-1) == 0  = f3 tail $ status
 | status !! (p2-1) == 1  = f3 tail $ set status p1 0
 | otherwise              = f3 tail $ set (set status p2 0) p1 1
```

With GHC and `-O2`, all four of these (your original code and these three variants) compile to identical low-level code, so use whichever you think is clearest.